# How to push changes to remote when we merge local branch

Tags: git

I have two remote branches, `variants` and `updates`. This `updates` branch I have created from `variants` branch. Now, I am inside `updates` branch in both remote and local branches.

Locally I merged `updates` branch with `variants` branch. How to push same changes to remote repo as well, to show only one branch `variants` merged with updates same as local? What command do I need to use?

Comment: once commited git push?

Comment: go to you variants branch and type `git merge updates` to merge `updates` into `variants`, solve conflicts if any

Comment: @ChrisG I already merged locally. Now how to do same for remote repository?

Comment: what do you use? github? gitlab? Bitbucket?

Comment: @ChrisG Gitlab.

Comment: `git push –u origin <branch name>`

Answer (score 0):

To push the merged changes to the remote repo, you can use the following command:

git push <remote_name> <local_branch_name>:<remote_branch_name>
Replace <remote_name> with the name of your remote repository, <local_branch_name> with the name of the branch you merged to, and <remote_branch_name> with the name of the branch you want to push the changes to. In your case, it would be:

git push origin variants:updates
This will push the merged changes from your local variants branch to the updates branch on the remote repository. After executing this command, you will see that both branches have the same history and changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).